# How to extract a value from a Vector in a column of a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

When using SparkML to predict labels the result Dataframe is:

```
scala> result.show
+-----------+--------------+
|probability|predictedLabel|
+-----------+--------------+
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.1,0.9]|           0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|
|  [0.1,0.9]|           0.0|
|  [0.6,0.4]|           1.0|
|  [0.6,0.4]|           1.0|
|  [1.0,0.0]|           1.0|
|  [0.9,0.1]|           1.0|
|  [0.9,0.1]|           1.0|
|  [1.0,0.0]|           1.0|
|  [1.0,0.0]|           1.0|
+-----------+--------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I want to create a new Dataframe with a new column named prob which is the first value from the Vector in probability column of original Dataframe e.g.:

```
+-----------+--------------+----------+
|probability|predictedLabel|   prob   |
+-----------+--------------+----------+
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.1,0.9]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.1,0.9]|           0.0|       0.1|
|  [0.6,0.4]|           1.0|       0.6|
|  [0.6,0.4]|           1.0|       0.6|
|  [1.0,0.0]|           1.0|       1.0|
|  [0.9,0.1]|           1.0|       0.9|
|  [0.9,0.1]|           1.0|       0.9|
|  [1.0,0.0]|           1.0|       1.0|
|  [1.0,0.0]|           1.0|       1.0|
+-----------+--------------+----------+
```

How can extract this value into a new column?

Comment: import org.apache.spark.ml.functions.vector_to_array and then model.withColumn("prob", vector_to_array(col("probability")).getItem(1)).show(false))

Answer (score 7):

You can use the capabilities of `Dataset` and the wonderful `functions` [library](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) to accomplish what you need:

`result.withColumn("prob", $"probability".getItem(0))`

This adds a new `Column` called `prob` whose value is derived from the `probability` `Column` by taking the first item (at index 0--we are computer scientists after all) in the array.

I would mention also that UDFs should be your last resort because the Catalyst optimizer cannot currently optimize UDFs, so you should always prefer the built-in functions to get the most out of Catalyst.

Comment: This would work with `ArrayType` not with `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT`.

Comment: Name: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException
Message: Can't extract value from probability#16416;
StackTrace:   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExtractValue$.apply(complexTypeExtractors.scala:73)

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple if you use Spark UDF(s). Like this:

```
val headValue = udf((arr: Seq[Double]) => arr.head)

result.withColumn("prob", headValue(result("probability"))).show
```

It will give you desired output:

```
+-----------+--------------+----------+
|probability|predictedLabel|   prob   |
+-----------+--------------+----------+
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.1,0.9]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.0,1.0]|           0.0|       0.0|
|  [0.1,0.9]|           0.0|       0.1|
|  [0.6,0.4]|           1.0|       0.6|
|  [0.6,0.4]|           1.0|       0.6|
|  [1.0,0.0]|           1.0|       1.0|
|  [0.9,0.1]|           1.0|       0.9|
|  [0.9,0.1]|           1.0|       0.9|
|  [1.0,0.0]|           1.0|       1.0|
|  [1.0,0.0]|           1.0|       1.0|
+-----------+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: `probability` output is `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT` not `ArrayType(DoubleType)`.

Comment: Could you please convert this to python